# No Static Files available

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

We have an old project - last commit was about 10 months ago.
The whole project runs without any problems and the last deployed version (about 10 months too) still running perfect.

A few days ago, I cloned the tool and was trying to start it.
Compilation was fine, but all webbrowsers dont get the static content (`*.css` or `*.js` as example).
We tried diffrent machines, but on all is the same error.

Network look like this:
[image: Network-traffic]

There are no changes on the code or the config. 
I think some system-componets (like the local `IIS`) got a update which not compatible with the old way to serve static files.
It makes no difference if windows-auth is on or off. Controller-Actions are fine, only the static files are problematic.

Has anybody a idea what can I check next? What informations can I provide to you? I have no idea what can I do next.

Comment: What path is it looking in? It's possible the paths are wrong, usually it should look for those files in `/Content`. That could not be the case. So best bet to verify where the 404s are looking for the files, and check in project they are where they are searched for.

Comment: The whole path looking like this: `http://localhost:58981/Content/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css` and the folders/files are also correctly in the project-folder.

Comment: [Take a look at this perhaps.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/)

Comment: In IIS what user is `Authentication > Anonymous Authentication` running as? Does that user have read permissions in the folder? Typically, this would be `IUSR` or `AppPool Identity`.

Comment: There is no IIS the "classic' way. I can only set the settings in Visual Studio. But it makes no diffrence if winows auth is on or off.

Comment: @Adriani6 we not using `requestFiltering`. Do you think the problem is here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it again ... :)
Visual Studio need to run as admin.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it ...
I removed this 3 lines from the `Web.config` and all worked as expected:

```
  <remove name="StaticFile" />
  <remove name="BlockViewHandler" />
  <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
```

## Edit

Today an other problem happend to me.
All static-files causing a 500. See the screen. (Windows-Auth turned on)
Anonymous-mode has no problems.
[image: 500]
[image: Detials of 500]